# Use of FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('RootName'), TYPE for 14K records makes SQL Query slow

Tags: xml, performance, sql-server-2012, query-performance, for-xml-path

I am working on Stored Procedure. 
Which uses view and converts the resultset table to XML format.
We have used the statement 'FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('toxicsite'), TYPE'.
The View is returning me the 14k records and after its getting converted to XML ... It takes 2 min.
Need help for another alternative or How I can Optimize the query Transform

Comment: Just to get this correctly: The query running without `FOR XML` is fast enough, but when you add `FOR XML` it slows done? How are you measuring the time? What are you doing with the XML? 14k records is quite a lot. XML is not designed for bigger data...

Comment: Yes... If I fetch data from view it return in 17 seconds (14k Records).But if I apply ForXML... Its a requirement .. I send this XML to API for further Processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this with a simple `SELECT TOP 14000 * FROM SomeBigTable`. SSMS is ready after 2 secs. With `FOR XML AUTO` it returns quite as fast. I do not think, that creating the XML is taking that long...

If your `VIEW` is very complex it might be, that `AUTO` is out tricking you. `AUTO` tries to find an appropriate internal structure for your query (nestings of related data)

As a *quick shot* you might try `FOR XML RAW,TYPE` just to check the performance difference. Best was an explicit approach with `FOR XML PATH`, where you can specify the nestings and relations yourself.

If there are BLOBs involved (`VARBINARY` data), you have the extra costs of converting this to `base64`, if there are many strings involved, especially if they have a lot of *non-latin* characters, you have the extra costs of entity encoding...

In general XML is astonishingly fast...